# Why for li with style float:left browser evaluates the height of the ul element to 0?

Tags: html, css

In the code presented on the gist : https://gist.github.com/1341600
I am trying to use ul/li elements for grouping together some search form elements (instead of table).
When inspecting the output in the browser (Chrome 15/FF 7 with firebug) the ul element seems to have height 0 and the li elements are displayed outside of it. When I am commenting out the

`float: left;` statement from `ul.search-inputs li` CSS declaration then the height of the ul element is displayed correctly.

Could anybody point me to a solution in order to see correctly the height of the ul element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> That's not a bug, it's a feature!

The container of a floated element is shrunken so that other inline elements will flow around it (as per specs).

The 3 options in this case are to:

1. Use a known height value and apply it to the `ul` element.

   ```
   ul { height: 150px; }
   ```
2. Use the `overflow` property on the `ul` element to force the browser to recalculate its height along with all the elements inside of it.

   ```
   ul { overflow: hidden; } /* hidden is preferred as it never adds scrollbars */
   ```
3. Float the container itself. As there is no need to shrink it if it floats by itself.

   ```
   ul { float: left; }
   ```

Comment: why is this a feature and not a bug ? why should the parent element be shruken ?

Comment: @user590849: That's because floated elements are "taken out of the document's flow", which means that a container with *only* floated elements, has no elements in the document flow, and hence the height is 0.

Answer (score 4):

Add following css:

```
ul.search-inputs {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/3QQHt/).

Comment: It is working. Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain me why needs the UL browser this style setting?

Comment: You have to stop the floating. You can stop it by adding a last element with css `clear: both` or you use the `overflow: hidden` at the parent element (because web-developer want to have the lowest number of dom elements).

Answer (score 2):

This behavior complies to W3C spec. It's deliberately, but can be a bit confusing first time. Container of the floated content must be shrunken to allow another inline content to flow around it's own one.

E.g. if you have a

```
<p>
    <img class="float" height="1000">
     sometext
</p> 
<p>
     sometext
</p>
```

you probably would expect that some text from the second p flow image.

If you need a container with width and height you can either specify them manually, or apply css overflow:auto or float:left to container;