# Javascript var doesn't apply the height of an ul as a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I made a script that makes my navigation bar stick to the top when scrolled below it. The problem was that my content 'jumped' up because of the space becoming available due to the navigation bars fixed property. Now I tried to fix it which worked when I gave it a % or px value via JS/JQuery. But once I tried giving it the proper value, which is the height of the navigation bar nothing worked anymore. So I guess the declaration must we wrong or am I missing a .toString() somewhere? Thank you.

Note that #Nav is the height of a ul, and not a div, in case that'd matter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = $('#Nav').offset().top; //var = space between Navbar and top of the page

  var stickyNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //var = top of viewport where the user currently is.
    var NavbarHeight = document.getElementById('#Nav').clientHeight; //var = height Navbar
    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
      $('#Nav').addClass('FixedNav'); //adds class 
      $('#Content').css("margin-top", NavbarHeight); //edits class
    } else {
      $('#Nav').removeClass('FixedNav'); //removes class
      $('#Content').css("margin-top", "auto"); //edits class
    }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(stickyNav());
});
```

Comment: *"So I guess the declaration must we wrong or am I missing a .toString() somewhere?'* Nope. `$('#Content').css("margin-top", NavbarHeight);` is perfectly valid if `NavbarHeight` is a number. jQuery will add the `"px"` for you: From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value): *"When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a string and add px to the end of that string."* Something *else* is wrong, like the value of `NavbarHeight`.

Comment: You could also do this `$(window).scroll(stickyNav);` instead of `$(window).scroll(function() {stickyNav();});`. Why call an anonymous function that then calls another function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I had figured out the problem would probably be in this line: var NavbarHeight = document.getElementById('#Nav').clientHeight;

Comment: And no idea why I did that @HristiyanDodov, Changed it right away.

Comment: @user6875529: That part should be fine to (`clientHeight` is a number [in pixels]). I haven't studied the script enough to know whether it's the right height property, but the units part is fine.

Comment: yeah I can't figure out what's wrong. It only works if I put the line where NavbarHeight gets a value in comments and change the margin-top to something like 10%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility that it does matter that you are using an **ul** and not a **div** container - if your **ul** contains floated **li** elements then it's height:

*The container of a floated element is shrunken so that other inline elements will flow around it (as per specs).*

See: [Why for li with style float:left browser evaluates the height of the ul element to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020935/why-for-li-with-style-floatleft-browser-evaluates-the-height-of-the-ul-element)

Try adding an explicit height to the **ul** (e.g: `height: 152px;`) or `overflow:hidden;` to get the browser to calculate the height of the **ul** correctly.

Edit: per your comment, that the script only works when have margin-top set as 10%, I think I am on the right track here. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is right, however, I also made the stupid mistake by putting a # when already called by the id using getElementById. It is surprising how you can overlook such a thing so easily.